# VBA - Count columns in an Range object

Tags: excel, vba, count, range

I wish to count the number of columns in my Range object - Rng.
Then I wish to use the Select Case operation to check that the user have not selected more than 1 column - if so the macro short abort.
I have not found anything about checking the nbr of columns in a Range.

- Either the code return 1 value - an absolute value of number of columns (e.g. 1 or 3 etc.)
- OR in some code to translate e.g. B-D to numeric values, for B and D respectively so I can take the numeric value of D-B to get the number of columns that the range object consist of.

Current code below (I know I need to chg:

```
    MsgBox "Select a continuous range of cells where numeric values should be appended."

    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8) 'Type Values, 8 - Range object

    FirstRowRng = Rng.Row
    LastRowRng = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1

    MsgBox FirstRowRng & LastRowRng
    MsgBox Range(Rng).Col.Count

    Select Case Columns(Rng) 'Here I want my case to check nbr of col on Rng

    Case 0:
    MsgBox "Nothing selected." & vbCrLf & "ERROR! Macro aborted."

    Case 1:
    MsgBox "Selected range: "
    'DO STUFF!!

    Case Else
    s = ""
    For Each r In Selection.Areas
      s = s + vbNewLine + r.Address(False, False)
    Next r
    MsgBox "Selected individual cells:" & s & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ERROR! Wrong selection - select a continuous range of cells where numeric values should be appended."

    End Select
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Rng.Columns.Count` is the column count just like your existing `Rng.Rows.Count` is for rows.

Comment: `Select Case Rng.column` (note that it is singular column not columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word in your code is ***continuous***.  If the user selects a nice block of cells *(rectangular)* or a single cell then:

```
rng.Columns.Count
```

will give you the count of columns.  If,however, the user selects a disjoint group of cells, then you would need to examine `rng.Areas.Count` first and then examine each `Area` next.